# Given a recursive definition of an object, how to write a recursive recognizer?

Tags: recursion, recursive-descent

I am studying for an exam and I am having trouble understanding this concept, given a recursive definition of an object, be able to write a recursive recognizer. I am not really sure how to do this.

Here is an example question:
A positive integer is a power of two if it is either 1 or two times a power of 2. Write a recursive recognizer for positive integers based directly on this recursive definition that recognizes whether the positive integer is a power of 2.

Comment: Is there any particular syntax or language you have used to describe a recognizer previously in the course?

Comment: Clarifying question: What format is the input? Are you lexing base 10 integers, or are you performing structural induction?

Comment: C++. Sorry I forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're looking for something like:

```
bool isPowerOf2(int x){
     if (x==1) return true;
     if (x mod 2 > 0) return false;
     return isPowerOf2(x/2);
}
```

This function will "try" to reach 1 by dividing the number by 2 each time, but will return false if x can't be divided exactly by 2 (if x modulo 2 is greater than 0).

Comment: Yes, that is somewhat what I was looking for. But would that function run successfully if I try to compile it in C++?